# How to do "format painter" in Google Sheets like Excel?

Tags: google-sheets

I do spreadsheet a lot and the "format painter" in Excel is very handy. Unfortunately I don't see it in google sheets. Google sheets is awesome so some large organizations only use it and don't offer Excel.
I wonder if there is a way to do "format painter" in Google Sheets?

Comment: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/161768?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop#zippy=%2Ccopy-text-formatting-paint-format, but your question does not appear to be about programming.

Answer (score 2):

you can use this: <kbd>CTRL + ALT + V</kbd>

[image]